# Matching Game - CARDS DON'T FLIP

Tags: java, swing

I am making a card matching game and I am having trouble making cards flip. For some reason, no matter which card I click, the last card flips and I can't figure out why that is the case. I want all cards to be able to be flipped.

Below is the code I currently have and I hope someone can help me where the problem/s is/are.

Thank you!!

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Image;

public class PlayingScreen extends JPanel {

    public static int cardonTable[] = new int [54];
    private CardButton cardonTableButton[] = new CardButton[54];
    int cardFlipAllowed = 2;
    public static boolean cardMatched;
    public static int clicked1;
    public static int clicked2;

    public PlayingScreen() {
        // variables used in loop
        Image dimg = null;
        ImageIcon dimgIcon = null;

        setLayout(null);

        CardDeal.createDeck(); //create a deck

        for(int i=0;i<54;i++) {
            cardonTable[i] = CardDeal.cardDeal();

            cardonTableButton[i] = new CardButton();

            if(i/9<=0) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+i*100+i*20, 50, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=1) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(+i-9)*100+(i-9)*20, 200+20, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=2) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(i-18)*100+(i-18)*20, 350+40, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=3) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(i-27)*100+(i-27)*20, 500+60, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=4) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(i-36)*100+(i-36)*20, 650+80, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=5) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(i-45)*100+(i-45)*20, 800+100, 100, 150);

            add(cardonTableButton[i]);

            BufferedImage img = null;
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource((cardonTable[i])+".png"));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //convert BufferedImage to ImageIcon
            dimg = img.getScaledInstance(cardonTableButton[i].getWidth(), cardonTableButton[i].getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            dimgIcon = new ImageIcon(dimg);

            // set front icon
            cardonTableButton[i].setFrontIcon(dimgIcon);

            try {
                // set back icon
                cardonTableButton[i].setBackIcon(new ImageIcon (ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("OVO_BACK.png"))));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int j = i;


            cardonTableButton[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener () {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if(cardFlipAllowed>0){

                    // retrieve CardButton from event
                    CardButton cardButton = (CardButton) e.getSource();
                    if(cardFlipAllowed==2) {
                    clicked1 = j ;
                    }
                    else {
                    clicked2 = j ;

                    Matched.matched(clicked1+1,clicked2+1); //see if they matched

                    System.out.println(clicked1);
                    System.out.println(clicked2);
                    System.out.println(cardMatched);


                    }
                    // Flip card. This method handles the logic of updating
                    // flipped and changing the icon
                    cardButton.flip();
                }
                    cardFlipAllowed--;
                }

            });

        }
    }

}
```

```
public class Matched {

    public static void matched(int cardNum1, int cardNum2) {

        //list of matches

        if (   (cardNum1==53&&cardNum2==54)||(cardNum1==54&&cardNum2==53)   ) {
            PlayingScreen.cardMatched = true;
        }

        else if(    (cardNum1<=13&& (cardNum2==cardNum1+13) ) || (cardNum2<=13&& (cardNum1==cardNum2+13) )   ) {
            PlayingScreen.cardMatched = true;

        }
        else if(    (cardNum1>=27&& (cardNum2==cardNum1+13) ) || (cardNum2>=27&& (cardNum1==cardNum2+13) )   ) {
            PlayingScreen.cardMatched = true;

        }
        else {
            PlayingScreen.cardMatched = false;
        }

        //1-14, 13-26
        //27-40. 39-52


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the time your event listener is called on each button, the variable j = 53. So each of your buttons is setting the icon in the 54th button. Instead, you want to change the icon of the button that issued the event.

Do this by changing the code in your `actionPerformed()` method:

```
    try {
        // retrieve JButton from event
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        // set icon
        btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon (ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("OVO_BACK.png"))));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**UPDATED:**

I've included code below for a custom CardButton class and modified PlayingScreen class. CardButton wraps a JButton and allows you to store the front and back images with getters/setters, and manage its flipped state using `flip()` method. This simplifies the code and gives you more flexibility in how and where you update the state of your card image.

Your `actionPerformed()` method now just calls the `flip()` method of the CardButton that created the event. All the logic is encapsulated in the CardButton class and segregated from the PlayingScreen class.

**CardButton**

```
public class CardButton extends JButton {
    private boolean flipped;
    private ImageIcon backIcon;
    private ImageIcon frontIcon;

    public CardButton() {
        super("");
    }

    /*
     * Flip the card
     */
    public void flip() {
        if (flipped) {
            setFlipped(false);
        } else {
            setFlipped(true);
        }
    }

    public boolean isFlipped() {
        return flipped;
    }

    /*
     * Updates flipped property and changes icon
     * based on flipped property
     */
    private void setFlipped(boolean flipped) {
        this.flipped = flipped;
        // show back icon when flipped = true
        if (flipped) {
            showBackIcon();

        // otherwise show front icon
        } else {
            showFrontIcon();
        }
    }

    public ImageIcon getBackIcon() {
        return backIcon;
    }

    public void setBackIcon(ImageIcon backIcon) {
        this.backIcon = backIcon;
        // set icon in parent JButton
        super.setIcon(backIcon);
    }

    public void showBackIcon() {
        super.setIcon(backIcon);
    }

    public ImageIcon getFrontIcon() {
        return frontIcon;
    }

    public void setFrontIcon(ImageIcon frontIcon) {
        this.frontIcon = frontIcon;
        // set icon in parent JButton
        super.setIcon(frontIcon);
    }

    public void showFrontIcon() {
        super.setIcon(frontIcon);
    }


}
```

**PlayingScreen**

```
public class PlayingScreen extends JPanel {

    private static int j = 0;
    private static int cardonTable[] = new int [54];
    private CardButton cardonTableButton[] = new CardButton[54];

    public PlayingScreen() {
        // variables used in loop
        Image dimg = null;
        ImageIcon dimgIcon = null;

        setLayout(null);

        CardDeal.createDeck(); //create a deck

        for(int i=0;i<54;i++) {
            cardonTable[i] = CardDeal.cardDeal();

            cardonTableButton[i] = new CardButton();

            if(i/9<=0) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+i*100+i*20, 50, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=1) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(+i-9)*100+(i-9)*20, 200+20, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=2) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(i-18)*100+(i-18)*20, 350+40, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=3) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(i-27)*100+(i-27)*20, 500+60, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=4) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(i-36)*100+(i-36)*20, 650+80, 100, 150);
            else if(i/9<=5) cardonTableButton[i].setBounds(50+(i-45)*100+(i-45)*20, 800+100, 100, 150);

            add(cardonTableButton[i]);

            BufferedImage img = null;
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource((cardonTable[i])+".png"));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //convert BufferedImage to ImageIcon
            dimg = img.getScaledInstance(cardonTableButton[i].getWidth(), cardonTableButton[i].getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            dimgIcon = new ImageIcon(dimg);

            // set front icon
            cardonTableButton[i].setFrontIcon(dimgIcon);

            try {
                // set back icon
                cardonTableButton[i].setBackIcon(new ImageIcon (ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("OVO_BACK.png"))));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            cardonTableButton[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener () {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // retrieve CardButton from event
                    CardButton cardButton = (CardButton) e.getSource();

                    // Flip card. This method handles the logic of updating
                    // flipped and changing the icon
                    cardButton.flip();
                }

            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!! I worked perfectly! I want the card to be able to flip back to the original one and I added the code I have currently. Can you help me figure out how to get the array position from the PlayingScreen method??

Comment: It would probably be easiest to extend JButton and make a custom class, Card for example, and store the front and back images and flipped state within it. Then you could change the image by calling a method on the Card class and you wouldn't have to worry about the array.

Comment: Is it possible to pass on a variable to actionPerformed...? I would like to pass int 'i' from PlayingScreen() as I can't picture how to switch pictures using custom class as you suggested..

Comment: I put the code into my code yesterday and I tried to fix it but I could not find what the problem is as I cant run/debug it...  While this website was on maintenance yesterday, I just took a picture of code and marked where they gave me errors.
Link to the picture is at the end of my question. Hope you can spot what's causing errors... Thanks again

Comment: I think you're just missing the imports for those classes. Press Ctrl+Shift+O with the file open. You can also copy the imports in the code in your question.

Comment: Oops I thought I added all but apparently I haven't... Although, I still have an error The constructor ImageIcon(Image) is undefined at dimgIcon = new ImageIcon(dimg); and the suggestion is to remove argument to match 'ImageIcon()' which if I do, does not solve any problem..

Comment: Make sure you have `import javax.swing.ImageIcon` and `import java.awt.Image`. If you have different imports for those classes, you would get an error saying the constructor is undefined

Comment: I had a different import instead of 'import java.awt.Image' and it works great now. Although, cards require two clicks at first to be flipped. Other than that, everything seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: Try adding `flipped = true;` to the CardButton constructor

Comment: I added it on declaration and works amazing! Thanks!

Comment: I added some codes above that will determine if the cards are matched but I am struggling to find a way to send the variable ' i ' to the class above when each cards are clicked..?

Comment: Add a field to the CardButton class and set it inside the loop. Then compare the fields from two CardButton objects in Matched

Comment: I am still not being able to pass on `i` to `actionPerformed` and I tried creating public static variable `j` that can be accessed from `actionPerformed` but it's not the correct variable. I think it's because at the moment when the code reaches that line, the loop is at a fixed point where `i` isn't the variable I need anymore or something. I have completely updated the code above so hopefully you can spot something! Thank you so much for helping me solve all these problems. I really appreciate it as I have no one to ask about this kind of stuff around me and you really are a life saver!!